# Why is my neighbor ping 20ms less in online games?

Tags: networking, ping

My friend/neighbor has the same ISP than me (cable provider). In fact, he has a lower speed package. But when we game online he always have 10-20ms less ping than me.

I tried connecting my PC directly to my modem and the result is still the same.

Our other friend in the same city with the same provider has arround my ping too. Why is that?

**EDIT:**

Here's the start of my tracert

```
  2    11 ms    17 ms     8 ms  10.33.104.1
  3    12 ms    14 ms    23 ms  216.113.124.61
  4     9 ms    14 ms     9 ms  216.113.122.154
```

Here's my friend's

```
2 8 ms 7 ms 7 ms 10.78.96.1
3 9 ms 11 ms 11 ms 216.113.126.170
4 7 ms 9 ms 8 ms 216.113.122.230
```

You can clearly see where i'm loosing those 15-20ms... The rest of the route is the same.

Comment: Yes but sometimes 20ms later means death in game.

Comment: @Sickest You've either never played a FPS or never really gotten invested in one, a ping of anything higher than 25 is bad, even 32.

Comment: Do you all have the same dns-server set? You can see this with `ipconfig /all` and if it's your routers ip you need to look in the router pages to see which dns-server it uses.

Comment: I'm using google's dns servers. I've now switched back to isp's ones. Reporting later.

Comment: Sounds like possible buffer bloat.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**: Check if your connection passes through an ISP proxy.

> Put in Google "What is my ip", choose one of the thousands similar
> webs and look where it says "Proxy Detected:".
> Repeat the same with your friend connection.

---

**Option 2**: Try a traceroute to the server game.

> For this open a prompt and type:
>
> Linux -> "traceroute [put_here_ip_server]"
>
> Windows -> "tracert [put_here_ip_server]"
>
> Compare both traceroutes.

---

If you have a Dynamic IP address, you can try to reboot your router to get a new IP and, hopefully, a better route to the server.

However, the best option will always be to hire FTTH(Fiber To The Home) to reduce the latency of the line.

Comment: No proxies both sides

Comment: Try a traceroute to the server game.

For this open a prompt and type:

 Linux -> "traceroute <put_here_ip_server>"

 Windows -> "tracert <put_here_ip_server>"

Compare both traceroutes.

Comment: I actualy can have FTTH to my home. But it's a new service and many people say it's not stable yet. 175mbps/175mbps is the max speed available

Answer (score 1):

If you pay attention to your tracert, you'll notice right away that your traceroute isn't even taking the same path as your neighbor -- your traffic is being routed through different hosts.

That said - and since you can't control it, nor can your neighbor - maybe you want to find other pursuits for your time rather than this sort of stuff.

Your question is akin to asking: "My co-worker lives next door to me.  We leave in the morning at the same time.  He takes his car, I take my car.  They're both Toyota Prius models.  Why don't we arrive at work within 20 ms of one another?"

Answer (score 0):

If you are serious about finding the answer, you'll need to remove variables.

- Cable Modem
- Router
- Coax and Network cables
- Network Card / Computer

The easiest one to test, would be to trade computers for a day.

My money would say that it is your network card / configuration is the biggest factor.

Different network chipsets perform differently. Just look at some of the video cards [marketed as low latency](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833342001). Supposedly firmware tweaks can take dozens of milliseconds off your ping.

If you try the computer swap experiment, please let me know how big of a difference it makes.